# Linking a CSS Folder rather than individual Files?

Tags: html, css

Just curious, couldn't really find any specific stuff on this topic but would it be acceptable rather than linking 10-20 css files to a page individually you could link a folder and it would encompass all the css files that are in that folder?Trying to cut back on the amount of code on my pages.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to php some code to check all the files you have inside a given folder and import them all. Just don't know how it would change your life. And why do you need so many css files?

Comment: For my neatness which isn't as neat as I'm finding out i created diffrent css files for diffrent types of things. For instance i have a main.css which is kinda div positioning and minor div framework, i also have form.css,font.css,links.css, tables.css and a few other for each type. I found my coding it that way was easier and faster for me to read but ended up looking like a wall of link tags on my index page lol

Comment: Sorry Andrew but that's not a good idea. Sooner or later you'll find yourself taking some time to find simple things among all those files. Also, the more css files you have, the more server requests you have (which is bad too). You should try using comments to better organize your CSS file and keep this number down to 1 or two files. It's good that you want to be organized. Actually, it's great! But try to organize it whithin one file.

Comment: Yea the more I think about it the more I feel I should just make a stylesheet and try to take the time to organize all my css and comment it properly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome Andrew! ps.: remember that's common practice to have special .css files for plugins and other stuff. ps2.: after some time, what I find that helps me the most is comment my CSS by "pages" or sections of a website, and if the project is too complex, bellow those pages/sections I have even more comments. If you keep it organized, you'll see that's not hard at all to keep track of your hard work ;)

Answer (score 3):

Combine your CSS files. Linking broadly to an entire directory is not really feasible.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't use folder references in your markup, but using CSS preprocessors such as LESS, SASS you definitely can eliminate having to load too many files by compiling them together.

**Check out these:**

http://lesscss.org/

http://sass-lang.com/

**And the real awesomeness:**

http://compass-style.org/

**There are very easy to set-up tools as well such as Scout:**

http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/

Answer (score 2):

Use @import to link to a single css that has a list of all the CSS files.

However, this is not good from a performance stand point.

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Answer (score 1):

you can make a single css document that imports all the others (using `@import url("import1.css");`) so you only call the base css doc.

Comment: using @imports in css files badly effect performance, so I would avoid that. http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Answer (score 0):

Combine them and minify them with something like YUI compressor http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/. Although that can be a pain if you are modifying your CSS often.

Or if you are in the .NET environment you can use Microsoft.Web.Optimization to auto bundle & minify entire folders of js and css.

It's less of an issue about the amount of code on your page, and more about the amount of HTTP Requests.